# Not able to receive window message in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, window

I want to send message to other process already running. What wrong...? why I am not able to receive messages
My sender code is as below

```
public partial class RegisterWindowMessage : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]

        //private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, string s, int i);

        const int WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;
        public RegisterWindowMessage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in procs)
            {
                if (p.ProcessName.Equals("TaskScheduling"))
                {

                    IntPtr hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, "This is the new Text!!!", 0);

                    MessageBox.Show("Inside");
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }
```

My receiver code is

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void frmReceiver_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
          //  this.lsvMsgList.Items.Add(e.KeyValue.ToString());
        }


        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(m.Msg.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(m.LParam.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(m.WParam.ToString());
            if (m.LParam.ToInt32() == 1)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to know why i am not able to receive message. Let me know where I am wrong

Comment: Looks like the `Form1` isn't the `MainWindowHandle`. You could try `EnumWindows` to enumerate all windows or Register a new message and use a broadcast.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code